# number is too low or too hight even if the guess is right

Tags: python, python-3.x

i'm a new programmer in python . i'm making a number guessing program . if the number guessed is equal to the random number it should print out 'right'. but for some reason the number is still low or still high.

```
import random
try :
    numb = int(input('enter the high lim : '))
    # gueses = 0

    while True :
        # gueses+=1
        a = random.randint(0,numb)
        b = int(input('enter the number : '))
    
        if a > b :
            print('too low')
        if a < b :
            print('too high')
        if a == b :
            print('right')
            break
    
        else :
            print('wrong')
# print(gueses)
except ValueError:
     print('enter an integer ')
```

and how do i calculate total number of guesses the user had made .

Comment: You're creating a new random number in each loop iteration. You only want to do this once before the loop…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @deceze suggested you're trying to guess the number in each loop. Hence initialize it only once and use it within the loop.

```
import random
try :
    numb = int(input('enter the high lim : '))
    # gueses = 0

    a = random.randint(0, numb)
    print(a)

    while True :
        # gueses+=1
        #a = random.randint(0,numb)
        b = int(input('enter the number : '))

        if a > b :
            print('too low')
        if a < b :
            print('too high')
        if a == b :
            print('right')
            break

        else :
            print('wrong')
# print(gueses)
except ValueError:
     print('enter an integer ')
```